# What is the "lightest" -> not messing with system registry antivirus

Tags: anti-virus

I am looking for antivirus for one shot. Just scan every piece of the system and delete the antivirus itself. I know that they are messing with system registry, slow down the system. I want to be sure that after reinstall it will dissappear completely.

Comment: No such animal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps an "Online" anti-virus scan like [Kaspersky](http://usa.kaspersky.com/downloads/free-anti-virus-scan)

You could also do an offline scan by downloading a rescue CD like [BitDefender](http://www.bitdefender.com/support/How-to-create-a-Bitdefender-Rescue-CD-627.html)

You could script something install, scan, and uninstall... but it's a bit more complicated.